# Angular: Update one-time binded data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose you have in your directive controller an array like

```
this.items = [
     {active: true, title: 'bar', ...},
     {active: false, title: 'foo', ...},
     ...
];
```

And in the template you visualise it

```
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="item in ::items" ng-class="...">{{item.title}}</li>
</ol>
```

Note the `::` which makes sure that it does this only once, because the directive injects some DOM elements too after `ng-repeat` is ready.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/1307/)

However, at some point in time the app receives an update

```
this.items = updatedItems;
```

The update is identical to the original data except for some of the properties of each item (`active` might change from `true` to `false` for example). Now, the update will not do anything because of the `::`. Now I can iterate through every item

```
updatedItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    $scope.items[index].active = item.active;                
    $scope.items[index].title = item.title;
    ...
});
```

So the question is what would be the best approach to this problem ?

Comment: Probably the best solution is to sort out the DOM element injection so you aren't forced into 1-way binding. As it stands you are trying to re-bind data which you have told Angular not to re-bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about having a copy of the dataset and data binding that, instead of the actual dataset, changes to which you want the template to ignore, all be it for a particular condition.

Then when you would want the data to be updated you can just update the necessary changes to the copied data and the changes will be reflected. I understand, that does add the overhead of having a copy of the data but a simple solution can often save from a lot of head scratching later, especially if the source is being looked at from a different member of the team.

Comment: Thnx. I think there is an other solution, which is to split the directive into smaller ones. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/1308/) In this case you can remove the one-time binding because you are no more manipulating the DOM yourself.